# Display Twitter Timeline in Android ListView

Tags: java, android, twitter

I'm pretty new to Android development and would appreciate some help. All I want is to display a ListView showing a Twitter timeline. I do this in an iPhone app using MGTwitter but I've been trying and am not sure how to get the same effect on Android. I can use a list view, but I'm not sure how to get the updates.

In a nutshell all it has to do is display the updates at www.twitter.com/user (User will be hardcoded).

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part you're asking for?  How to pull the data from twitter on your device, or (assuming you have the data) how to display it?

Comment: I mean just pulling the timeline data from twitter. i.e. a list of my 10 most recent status updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some dedicated library eg. [Twitter 4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)