# How to make listview like listview Twitter

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, slide

I want to create a ListView like in ListView twitter..
when the list items on a slide, so you will have the option to reply, retweet, etc. (not the quick actions).

Can you give an example for my problem?

thanks before :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here: [Display Twitter Timeline in Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138307/display-twitter-timeline-in-android-listview)
and maybe here also: http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/56268.aspx

Comment: thank you for your answer: D

I mean here is when an item in the ListView in the slide, will show a new view in the same place ... you can see an example on twitter application for android (most recent)..