# XML Layout for Tweet

Tags: android, android-layout

I am going to customize an XML Layout for individual tweets.  I would like to base it off as much as possible the standard layout for tweets.  Does anyone know where I can find this layout.  I don't want to reinvent the wheel here just use represent the tweet in the standard way.

Comment: take a look at this similar post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552968/how-to-make-listview-like-listview-twitter

Comment: looked at that, but it is not exactly what I am looking for. I really would like to more or less match the standard twitter client layout for an individual tweet.  This question is 100% about the layout of one single tweet. Including how recent in upper right corner etc. Font for the tweet the different parts of the tweet etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [listview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Comment: Yes listview will be part of this. What I am after is the exact layout of an individual tweet.

Answer (score 0):

twitter_list_row.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/username"
    android:text="@string/line"
    android:textColor="#777777" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ago"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/line"
    android:textColor="#777777"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/at_line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ago"
    android:text="@string/line"
    android:textColor="#777777" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/at_username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/at_line"
    android:textColor="#777777"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textColor="@color/header_text"
    android:textColorLink="#00FF00" />
```

Comment: looks like this is missing the imageview and also the containing layout.